# React + Vite js project are occur error in build file

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

Some chunks are larger than 1600 KiB after minification. Consider:

- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.built in 85285ms.

I try all solution which given in stack overflow and github.

I remove all unusable content of project, use lazy loading, remove all comment , but still not working.

my viteconfig.js file here

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2000},
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: "@", replacement: "/src" }],
  },
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
    },
    host: true, // needed for the Docker Container port mapping to work
    strictPort: true,
    port: 80, // you can replace this port with any port
  },
  preview: {
    port: 80,
  },
  
});
```